# Making two queries by category

Tags: php, wordpress

Trying to make two Queries for posts. Other one for categories 13 and 14 and other one for the rest. When I have this code it will just post everything, when it should not include 13 and 14.

(*The final goal is that everytime i post something with category 13, it will copy one category 14 post, being always the same post with same id, and post it after category 13 is posted )*

```
if ( ! function_exists('vpsa_posts_shortcode') ) {
    function vpsa_posts_shortcode( $atts ){

        $atts = shortcode_atts( array(
                        'per_page'  =>      10,  
                        'order'     =>  'DESC',
                        'orderby'   =>  'date',
                        'category__not_in'  =>  array( 13,14 )
                ), $atts );

        $paged = ( get_query_var('paged') ) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;

        $args = array(
            'post_type'         =>  'post',
            'posts_per_page'    =>  $atts["per_page"], 
            'order'             =>  $atts["order"],
            'orderby'           =>  $atts["orderby"],
            'paged'             =>  $paged,
            'category__not_in'  =>  array( 13,14 )
        );

        $query = new WP_Query($args);
        
/* Here checking if output has posts */
        
                if($query->have_posts()) : $output;

/* Making the loop for output and getting all kind of fun stuff from the database */            
        
                    while ($query->have_posts()) : $query->the_post();

                            $output .= '<div class="arkisto-uutiskuva"><a alt="' . the_title('','',false) . '" href="' . get_post_permalink() . '"><div class="arkisto-kuva">' . get_the_post_thumbnail() . '</div></a></div>';
                            $output .= '<h2 class="arkisto-title"><a href="' . get_permalink() . '" title="' . the_title('','',false) . '">' . the_title('','',false) . '<span class="arkisto-date"> (' . get_the_date() .')</span></a></h2>';
                                    $output .= '<p class="arkisto-teksti">' . get_the_excerpt() .'</p><br>';



          
                    endwhile;global $wp_query;
$args_pagi = array(
        'base' => add_query_arg( 'paged', '%#%' ),
        'total' => $query->max_num_pages,
        'current' => $paged
        );
                    $output .= '<div class="post-nav">';
                        $output .= paginate_links( $args_pagi);


                    $output .= '</div>';

                else:

                    $output .= '<p>Sorry, there are no posts to display</p>';

                endif;

        
/* This is something not so important for the issue, I dont know how to explain in English */
        
            wp_reset_postdata();

            return $output;
    }
}

add_shortcode('vpsa_posts', 'vpsa_posts_shortcode');
```

Comment: What have you tried to resolve the problem? Where are you stuck?

Comment: I have tried to write the "'category__not_in'  =>  array( 13,14 )" part of the code in different ways but I think now it should be right, just still not working

Comment: Now im trying to use this 

`function exclude_category($query) {
    if ( $query->is_home() ) {
    $query->set('cat', '-13,-14');
    }
    return $query;
    }
    add_filter('pre_get_posts', 'exclude_category');

function include_category($query_viikonkuva) {
    if ( $query_viikonkuva->is_home() ) {
    $query_viikonkuva->set('cat', '13,14');
    }
    return $query_viikonkuva;
    }
    add_filter('pre_get_posts', 'include_category');  `